# Fluent NHibernate mapping IDictionary<string, class> in a smart way

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Given these classes:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FluentMappingsQuestion
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual IDictionary<string, Property> Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class Property
    {
        public virtual Entity OwningEntity { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Value { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal OtherValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I map them using NHibernate (preferably fluent flavor) so that doing this is possible:

```
[Test]
public void EntityPropertyMappingTest()
{
    using (var session = _factory.OpenSession())
    {
        var entity = new Entity();

        // (#1) I would *really* like to use this
        entity.Properties["foo"] = new Property { Value = 42, OtherValue = 42.0M };

        session.Save(entity);
        session.Flush();

        // (#2) I would like the entity below to "update itself"
        // on .Save or .Flush. I got it to work with .Load()
        Assert.AreEqual(42, entity.Properties["foo"].Value);
        Assert.AreEqual(42.0M, entity.Properties["foo"].OtherValue);
        Assert.AreEqual("foo", entity.Properties["foo"].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(entity, entity.Properties["foo"].Owner);
    }
}
```

I have almost managed to do this with these mappings:

```
// class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
public EntityMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    HasMany(x => x.Properties)
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .KeyColumn("EntityId")
    .AsMap(x => x.Name);
}

// class PropertyMap : ClassMap<Property>
public PropertyMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.OwningEntity).Column("EntityId");
    Map(x => x.Name).Length(32);
    Map(x => x.Value);
{
```

The problems I have:

- If I make `Entity.Properties` `.Inverse()`, it starts breaking
- If I don't make it `.Inverse()` then NHibernate does: `INSERT(Entity), INSERT(Property), UPDATE(Property)` instead of just `INSERT(Entity), INSERT(Property)`
- If I make `Property.Name` `.Not.Nullable()`, it starts breaking
- If I don't make it `.Not.Nullable()`, I have a hole in my db schema

How should I change my mappings?

Comment: If you really want to be able to use code like:

entity.Properties["foo"] = 42;

Then why have you created this Property class? Why not just do the usual thing of having a IDictionary<string,int> and then map it as a NHibernate map?

Comment: @Paul: Ideally, I would like to be able to use this with classes, with inheritance, too. The code example I pasted seems to be a bit unclear on this. I'll update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked around this by specifying this mapping:

```
HasMany<Property>(Reveal.Member<Entity>("InternalProperties"))
  .AsMap(p => p.Name)
  .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
  .Inverse();
```

and creating two properties of type `IDictionary<string, Property>`: `Properties` and `InternalProperties`. The first one is a proxy dictionary over the second one, and deals with setting the `OwningEntity` and `Name` properties for the `Property` entries.